# How to parse array inside form post

Tags: go

I currently have a form post that is coming in like

```
{
 "stuff":"cool text",
 "otherthing":"neat thing",
 "captions":[
     {"first":"the list",
     "second":"how are you"},
     {"first":"wow",
     etc....
  ]
}
```

Now I don't know how many captions there will be.  It might be one in the array, it might be twenty.

I have set up two structures as well

```
type ThingContext struct {
    Stuff       string  `json:"stuff"`
    OtherThing  string  `json:"otherthing"`
    Captions    []ArrayText `json:"captions"`
}

type ArrayText struct {
    First    string  `json:"first"`
    Second   string  `json:"second"`
}
```

And in my golang function I have something like this

```
func (c *ThingContext) SetThingContext(rw web.ResponseWriter, req *web.Request, next web.NextMiddlewareFunc) {
    if err := req.ParseForm(); err != nil {
    }
    c.Stuff = req.FormValue("stuff")
    c.OtherThing = req.FormValue("otherthing")
}
```

This works fine till I try and parse the array.
When I do something along the lines of `c.Captions = req.ParseForm("captions")`
I get the error

```
.cannot use req.Request.ParseForm("captions") (type error) as type []ArrayText in assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right, except for the assignment. When you run req.Request.ParseForm(), rather than returning a value, or passing in a reference to a buffer, it populates the req.Request.Form and req.Request.PostForm structures.

[The related GoDoc explaining said function](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.ParseForm)

So rather than

```
c.Captions = req.Request.ParseForm()
```

It would look more like

```
err := req.Request.ParseForm()
//check for errors as usual here
c.Captions = req.Request.Form
//or
c.Captions = req.Request.PostForm
```

Approaching it from this direction should put you on the right track.

Cheers!
Taylor

Comment: It gives me `cannot use req.Request.Form (type url.Values) as type []ArrayText in assignment`, so perhaps I might have to do `c.Captions = req.Request.Form["captions"]`?

Comment: You're on the right track. You probably want to marshall the data into your structures using the encoding/json built in library. The godoc for json is pretty confusing, but this page has a decent explanation. https://www.dotnetperls.com/json-go

Comment: So for a marshaller you have a few options, read the data in to an unmarshaller if you have the raw json data, or you can parse the url.Values, which should become a simple string once you call .Encode() on the url.Values. Sorry for the multiple posts, new here.